# How to check network settings?

Tags: command-line, 20.04

I am running Ubuntu Focal 20.04 and I'd like to get information about the network. For that purpose, I'm using the shell to run the following command, which outputs plenty of staff:

```
ifconfig -a
```

All seems to be working well till I run:

```
ifconfig eth0
```

When running the last command, I get:

```
eth0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

I don't get what I'm doing wrong! Any help?

Comment: `eth0` seems to be a wrong interface name.

Comment: " ifconfig -a & get plenty of staff." it is custom to add the result to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You (and all of us) do not have an `eth0` for years now. Ubuntu uses predictive names.  `ifconfig -a` shows you the name you need to feed `ifconfig`.

Example from my machines:

```
$ ifconfig -a
...
wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500    
        inet 192.168.178.19  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::b971:f72f:c416:2a96  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fc:77:74:bc:87:43  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2733275  bytes 3448410896 (3.4 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1070857  bytes 381490320 (381.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So for me `ifconfig wlo1` will show what you are asking the system with `eth0`.

Comment: Books am readin seem to be old-fashioned !!! THANKS @Rinzwind

Comment: @DanielBernardoGraset Hi! If you think that this answer is helpful, you are encouraged to upvote it and also accept it as the solution, if it solves your problem! That way, other users faced with the same problem as you will know that this is a useful answer.